# SQL lookup value per closest earlier date in other table

Tags: sql, datetime, left-join, query-optimization, window-functions

Re [the solution to this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27823/query-to-find-closest-lesser-date/275724), wouldn't the *correlated subquery* be executed many times? Can you guys think of **any other query that would perform better on really big datasets?**

Rather than using joins with corralated subquery, maybe by leveraging *LAG/LEAD functions*? I'm just wondering.. I would appreciate any input or idea to solve some performance issue I'm facing with similar problem.. I've been searching the net and already tried various solutions like using *row_number()* for instance but found nothing that would perform any better so far..

```
CREATE TABLE EXCHANGE_RATES (
VALID_FROM date,
RATE decimal
);

CREATE TABLE ENTRIES (
ID int NOT NULL,
DATE date,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO EXCHANGE_RATES VALUES
 ('2020-01-01', 101)
 --2020-01-02 missing
,('2020-01-03', 103)
,('2020-01-04', 104)
,('2020-01-05', 105)
 --2020-01-06 missing
 --2020-01-07 missing
 --2020-01-08 missing
,('2020-01-09', 109)
;

INSERT INTO ENTRIES VALUES 
 (1, '2020-01-02')
,(2, '2020-01-03')
,(3, '2020-01-04')
,(4, '2020-01-08')
;
```

And the current solution:

```
SELECT
 e.*
,r.RATE
FROM
ENTRIES e
LEFT JOIN EXCHANGE_RATES r
 ON r.VALID_FROM = (select max(VALID_FROM) from EXCHANGE_RATES where VALID_FROM <= e.DATE)
;
```

Results are fine just looking for a better way if any:

```
ID  DATE        RATE
1   2020-01-02  101
2   2020-01-03  103
3   2020-01-04  104
4   2020-01-08  105
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: okay, will fabricate them momentarily..

Comment: added samples..

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are talking about.  Or be very explicit on how you are using multiple databases.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approch uses a lateral join:

```
select e.*, er.*
from entries e
outer apply (
    select rate, valid_from
    from exchange_rates er
    where er.valid_from <= e.date
    order by er.valid_from desc
    offset 0 rows fetch next 1 row only
) er
```

This syntax should work in Oracle and SQL Serer, which you both tagged. An index on `exchange_rate(valid_from, rate)` might help speed up the query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fd946e1f5299f42cfd6d14f11c37ace2)**:

```
ID | DATE       | rate | valid_from
-: | :--------- | ---: | :---------
 1 | 2020-01-02 |  101 | 2020-01-01
 2 | 2020-01-03 |  103 | 2020-01-03
 3 | 2020-01-04 |  104 | 2020-01-04
 4 | 2020-01-08 |  105 | 2020-01-05
```

Comment: nice one, thanks, though doesn't seem to perform much better on my live data/system for some reason actually..

Comment: @Tom: do you have the recommended index in place?

Comment: yep, got a clustered index in place on those cols

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach a lot on Teradata where non-equi-joins are not very efficient.

First UNION both tables adding NULLs:

```
select id
  ,date
  ,NULL as rate
  ,NULL as valid_from
from ENTRIES
union all
select NULL as id
  ,valid_from
  ,rate
  ,valid_from
from EXCHANGE_RATES
order by 2,1

 id   date        rate  valid_from 
      2020-01-01  101   2020-01-01 
 1    2020-01-02                   
      2020-01-03  103   2020-01-03 
 2    2020-01-03                   
      2020-01-04  104   2020-01-04 
 3    2020-01-04                   
      2020-01-05  105   2020-01-05 
 4    2020-01-08                   
      2020-01-09  109   2020-01-09
```

Then fill the missing data using LAG:

```
with union_rows as 
 (
    select id
      ,date
      ,NULL as rate
      ,NULL as valid_from
    from ENTRIES
    union all
    select NULL as id
      ,valid_from
      ,rate
      ,valid_from
    from EXCHANGE_RATES
 )
,fill_data as
 (
   select id, date 
     ,lag(rate,1,rate) 
      over (order by date,id) as rate
     ,max(valid_from) 
      over (order by date,id
            rows unbounded preceding) as valid_from
   from union_rows
 )
select * 
from fill_data

 id   date       rate   valid_from  
      2020-01-01  101   2020-01-01 
 1    2020-01-02  101   2020-01-01 
 2    2020-01-03        2020-01-01 
      2020-01-03        2020-01-03 
 3    2020-01-04  103   2020-01-03 
      2020-01-04        2020-01-04 
      2020-01-05  104   2020-01-05 
 4    2020-01-08  105   2020-01-05 
      2020-01-09        2020-01-09
```

and finally filter the rows from ENTRIES

```
 where id is not null
```

This works well as long as there's only a single row per date/table, i.e. only a single NULL between rows. If there're multiple NULL rows you need LAG's IGNORE NULLS option, which is not supported by SQL Server.

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da6f845f74be8b5f80a97f870de53594)

Comment: Right, have more nulls/gaps in my live data so I guess would need IGNORE NULLS after all.. I'll try to move my data to Oracle and try this solution out, looks really promosing, thank you!

Comment: well, tried this approach out with option IGNORE NULLS on my live data, but doesn't seem to perform better in my case unfortunately.. don't know why but it's a cool idea anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The question that you are referencing was asked **eight** years ago.

In any case `lag()` and `lead()` work when the data is in a single table.  That question is about asking for the nearest value in *another* table.  The correlated subquery is a reasonable approach.

There are other methods as well -- but those depend on the particular problem.

Comment: Right, I was thinking to generate VALID_TO values in the other table first for example so can rely something more than the VALID_FROM dates alone if it makes sense..